# What is the context in Async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am running an Async(doInBackground) task in android.

I need to populate a progress bar for the task. So i am showing a progressDialog in onPreExecute,

The signature of ProgressDialog.show is Show(Context,Title,message)

But what would be the **Context** here?

```
 @Override
protected void onPreExecute() 
{
    progress = ProgressDialog.show(???, "Loading", "Please Wait");
}
```

Comment: Just initialize Context context=this; inside the onCreate () method. It contain for current Activity only

Comment: paste your code that will help,where you define your async task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a constructor for your AsyncTask that takes a context as a parameter.

```
public class async extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    private Context context;

    public async(Context context) {
      this.context = context;
     }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
     // Manipulate progress bar      
    }
```

Then use this to execute it

```
async mTask = new async(context).execute(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

Context can be only of Activity ,Service or Brodcast not of any other class like Asyncktask.So put the Context of that Activity where you are using that AsyncTask class.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the activity context in the AsyncTask constructor to create the ProgressDialog :

MyAsyncTask constructor :

```
public MyAsyncTask(Context context){
     progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, "Loading", "Please wait...");
}
```

onPreExecute method :

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() 
{
    progressDialog.show();
}
```

or store the context and create the dialog in the onPreExecute methods (but I prefer use the first way) :

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask{
     private Context mContext;

     public MyAsyncTask(Context context){
          this.mContext = context; 
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() 
     {
          progress = ProgressDialog.show(this.mContext, "Loading", "Please Wait");
     }
}
```

And in activity when you declare MyAsyncTask, you pass the activity:

```
MyAsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask(this);
asynchTask.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Add this function in your class

   private Context getDialogContext() {
    Context context;
    if (getParent() != null)
        context = getParent();
    else
        context = this;
    return context;
}

In your asynctask use it as follows

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() 
  {
    progress = ProgressDialog.show(getDialogContext(), "Loading", "Please Wait");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use only `this` as context then your Asynctask should be written as an inner class of a class which extends the Activity class. Then your context is the name of the class which extends Activity. Still it is better practice to pass the context like this:

```
ClassExtendingActivity.this
```

Answer (score -1):

you can pass current activity view reference like `MainActivity.this`

Comment: Missing a part 'how' you pass it to AsyncTask, it doesn't have it defaultly. You have to create it your own.

Comment: sorry i cannot understan how to pass meance??

Comment: I mean, how does the AsyncTask get the reference of MainActivity.this. It won't work if it's in a seperate file. You should give the Context to it via a function or constructor, see Kuffs answer.

Comment: ya you right i am thinking that way but i got minus rate then i stop to thinkk.